# How to find elements of a list are subset of string using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am a Molecular Biologist and new to programming, so excuse me for my language. I am working with python.

Example:

```
string = "gctatagcgttatatactagcctatagctata"

list = ["gtagctaggac", "mptalltruiworw", "12365478995", "nvncmvncmvncmvn"]
```

now coming to question
I want to know a method which can discover that

```
for element in list:
  if element is subset of string (in any order)
  return element
```

In above example the answer should be

```
gtagctaggac
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "in any order" means? Are you saying any permutation of the element? So if element is "acb" and string contains "bca" the if statement evaluates to true?

Comment: yes any permutation... I tried permutations but they make algorithm very bulky and computer halts at the end...

Comment: Follow up - if the string is "adcb" and the element is "bca" does that evaluate to false - essentially, is this a subsequence problem or a subset problem?

Comment: Also, does the number of elements matter? I guess that "aa" is in the string "aba" but not in "abc"?

Comment: hm... element is subset of string... and its perfect subset... it may be equal to string but no other component or a set larger than string should be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spend time generating permutations, compare the number of letters in the list element and the string. Note that this code doesn't check for letters in the string that are not in the pattern.

```
string = "gctatagcgttatatactagcctatagctata"
list = ["gtagctaggac", "mptalltruiworw", "12365478995", "nvncmvncmvncmvn"]

from collections import defaultdict

def count_letters(string):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for letter in string:
        counts[letter] += 1
    return counts

sc = count_letters(string)

for element in list:
    counts = count_letters(element)
    if all([sc[letter] >= counts[letter] for letter in counts]):
        print "Found", element
```

As a matter of style, it's better not to use the names of built-in classes like "list" and "string".

Comment: Peter, for clarification see my comment. He is asking if any permutation of the element is in the string.

Comment: THank you Peter and C.B for your help... it will surely work for me.